# MS Access Reference to Recordset.Recordcount

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba

I need to find out if there is a record in my

1. Main forms [frmShiftDay]
2. Subform [frmShiftMachinesSubform]
3. SubSubform [frmMachineOutputSubform]

and I can’t get it to reference at all. Thanks!

```
ElseIf Me!frmMachineOutputSubform.Form!frmMachineOutputSubform.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Product Name is missing", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Required Data!"
    Me.frmShiftMachinesSubform.Form.frmMachineOutputSubform.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing one last "form"

```
ElseIf Me.frmMachineOutputSubform.Form.frmMachineOutputSubform.Form.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
```

Comment: No that doesnt work either... I can only get it to work if I have the VBA below on my subform but I need it on my main form. The code below ONLY works on the "Subform" >>>>ElseIf Me.frmMachineOutputSubform.Form.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then<<<<<

Comment: I am wondering about those  ! What happens when you replace them with a period.

Comment: I tried it without ! and replaced with periods but still. mabe you can onl reference one subform? Any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
ElseIf Me.frmMachineOutputSubform.frmMachineOutputSubform.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
```

Comment: Same thing happens. Is there another way I can check if I have a record basicly the same way? I did try putting a text box on my subsub form with =count([myid]) but it only updates the record count if I add a new record.any thee ways you guys can think of is much appreciated. Thanks!